# draw hebrew text to image (python,PIL)

Tags: python, text

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Drawing Hebrew text to and image using Image module (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182787/drawing-hebrew-text-to-and-image-using-image-module-python)

this is the code:

```
import Image
import ImageDraw
import ImageFont
import _imaging

a=u'1אריאל' #u'..' converts to unicode
font = ImageFont.truetype('c:/test/Miriam.ttf',24) #standard hebrew font, this line throws the error
im=Image.new('RGB',(200,200),(100,100,100))
d=ImageDraw.Draw(im)
d.text((0,0),a)
im.show()
```

this is the error:ImportError: The _imagingft C module is not installed

what can I do??

thanks

Comment: Exact duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182787/drawing-hebrew-text-to-and-image-using-image-module-python